# Golang gorilla expects trailing slash on static serving

Tags: go, gorilla

I want to serve the swagger-ui using gorilla/mux and http.FileServer.

This is the routing that works so far:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.PathPrefix("/swagger-ui/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/swagger-ui/", 
http.FileServer(http.Dir("swagger-ui/"))))
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
```

The problem is: only a GET /swagger-ui/ returns the swagger page.
When I do (what most users also expect) a GET /swagger-ui without trailing slash I get a 404.

How can this be solved?

Comment: The simplest solution is to add route `/swagger-ui` and redirect with 301 http code to `/swagger-ui/`. This is in case when gorilla can't help you in more elegant way :-)

Comment: Because you are stripping `/swagger-ui/`. and `/swagger-ui` is not equal to `/swagger-ui/`, so that't not being removed/stripped, resulting 404!

Comment: Ok, thanks, but doesn't give me any clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

You have probably found the answer as the question is nearly two years old, but I will write the answer here so that anybody who comes across this question can see it.

You just need to define your gorilla router as:
`router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)`

> StrictSlash func(value bool) *Router StrictSlash defines the trailing
>   slash behavior for new routes. The initial value is false.
>
> When true, if the route path is "/path/", accessing "/path" will
>   perform a redirect to the former and vice versa. In other words, your
>   application will always see the path as specified in the route.
>
> When false, if the route path is "/path", accessing "/path/" will not
>   match this route and vice versa.
>
> The re-direct is a HTTP 301 (Moved Permanently). Note that when this
>   is set for routes with a non-idempotent method (e.g. POST, PUT), the
>   subsequent re-directed request will be made as a GET by most clients.
>   Use middleware or client settings to modify this behaviour as needed.
>
> Special case: when a route sets a path prefix using the PathPrefix()
>   method, strict slash is ignored for that route because the redirect
>   behavior can't be determined from a prefix alone. However, any
>   subrouters created from that route inherit the original StrictSlash
>   setting.

Comment: This does not work with pathprefix set, as per the docs, which you quote.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to the issue with the trailing slash.

Suffix slash is the most annoying thing when the request method is different than `"GET"` as there is no use of `r.StrictSlash(true)`.

Instead of writing complex or inelegant solutions like multiplying the `r.HandlerFunc` routes for `"/path"` and `"/path/"`, a middleware might come useful:

```
func routingMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        url := *r.URL
        url.Path = strings.TrimSuffix(r.URL.Path, "/")
        r.URL = &url

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

And wherever your `mux.Router` is - do this:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.Use(routingMiddleware)
```

Hope it helps!